# Clarifying the manual count of Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: java, metrics, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

Let's assume that we have a code like this:

```
switch(y)
{
case 1: case 2: case 3:
    function();
    break;
case 4: case 5: case 6:
    function_2();
    break;
}
```

Can we get the CC value as 6+1 here? Why a value of 1 is added? If the CC value is considered as 7, is that the number of independent paths?

What if a fall through scenario is considered above? As only possible two unique paths are there, 2 +1 =3

Which of the above are correct or are the both of them correct?

Comment: There are three (distinct) paths through this switch, not two.

Comment: 7th case is when `y` is neither 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 nor 6.

Comment: To try answering the question, I would say CC must be defined in terms of what the code is logically doing, not what the processor will actually do (and we don't even know what it will do most of the time). We don't care if the `2` is going to visit less cases of the `switch` because we definitely know that in the end it will reach the same state as the `3`. I have a strong preference for saying the CC is 3 here

Comment: @Raphaël cyclomatic complexity is not about runtime comparisons or evaluations. It's a metric that can be calculated statically (at compile-time)

Comment: Yeah, 3 seems to be correct.But if the given snippet is ran through a tool like RSM ,it outputs a value of 7 as the CC value. Maybe both the values are correct?

Comment: The tool is likely considering each `case` label, e.g., it's really falling through `case 4:` to `case 5:`. IMO not necessarily the most useful way of looking at it, but whatever.

Comment: So its basically like,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but if the y=2, the code will skip case 1 and jump to case 2 and 3 right, so if we write the above same code with IF conditions, we will get a CC of 7.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, `CC = P+1.`

Here, P = number of predicate nodes (conditions) = 2

Number of conditions will be 2 because:

> Case branch can cover several alternative values or ranges, such as
>   Case 1, 2, 5 To 10. As they introduce no additional branches to decide
>   on, they do not increase cyclomatic complexity either.

source: [here](http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-complexity.html)

So, CC = 2+1 = 3

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but if the y=2, the code will skip case 1 and jump to case 2 and 3 right, so if we write the above same code with IF conditions, we will get a CC of 7.